# Custom scripts in Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Since `scripts` directory is gone in Rails 4, where am I excepted to put my custom Shell and Ruby scripts? `bin`, `lib`, or maybe just restore `scripts` directory for stuff like this?

Answer (score 0):

I use lib for all my custom scripts.

Just add this to your application.rb to load this directory together with your project: `config.eager_load_paths += %w(#{config.root}/lib)`